# Why does `sed -e 's/[0-9]*/& &/'` have very different results with minor input changes?

Tags: unix, sed

I am trying to understand the below result and differences, why the result is not **abc 123 123** when [0-9]* would match 123

- Why is this first answer not `abc 123 123`?

  ```
  $ sed -e 's/[0-9]*/& &/' <<<'abc 123'
   abc 123
  ```
- Why is the second result `123 123 abc`?

  ```
  $ sed -e 's/[0-9]*/& &/' <<<'123 abc'
  123 123 abc
  ```
- Why does the third one have extra spaces?

  ```
  $ sed -e 's/[0-9]*/& &/g' <<<'abc 123'
   a b c  123 123
  ```

Comment: Please try to ask your questions formulated to still be understandable by people who can't view screenshots, for the reasons described in [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: Also, in general, only ask one question to a question. The third bullet point is almost an entirely different question from the other two (and importantly, it's already been asked and answered elsewhere in our knowledgebase, so if it was asked standing alone we could have just closed the question as a duplicate; instead, the whole thing becomes eligible for close as "too broad").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` will use the first match. Since `[0-9]*` matches not just 3 digits `123` but also 0 digits (the empty string), it will match the empty string marked with parentheses here: `()abd 123` and replace it with `() ()abd 123`

If you instead use one of:

```
sed -r 's/[0-9]+/& &/'
sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/& &/'
```

then you require that it matches *at least* 1 digit, and then it'll behave the way you expect.

Comment: when you say empty string its a word boundary? Yes this time i see in the result a space , so is it <WB><SPACE><WB>abc 123? for the first question

Comment: It's unrelated to word boundaries. Here are the word boundaries marked with `|`: `|abc| |123|`. Here are possible matches for empty strings (there's 0 characters between `a` and `b`, so the empty string matches there): `|a|b|c| |1|2|3|`

Comment: understood finally, as soon as sed finds first match 0 character length (I name zero character as "|" for my understanding) from pattern /[0-9]*/ it replace with |<space>| so the final result is :  "|<space>||a|b|c| |1|2|3|" ?